# Choosing a size for a buffer

Tags: c

I'm confused, when allocating memory with `malloc` you have to provide a size, however, it sometimes happen that you don't know the size you need at that point so you either alloc a huge amount of memory (which doesn't sound too wise since you're probably not going to use it all) or you use `realloc` when the initial buffer size becomes too small. Are this two options valid? The second one sounds good, however, the docs say that `realloc` `...may move the memory block to a new location` which sounds like a very bad idea/hard to handle situation (e.g. if you have multiple pointers pointing to the same address the moment you call `realloc` they all become invalid) I'm a beginner with C, can somebody explain me how to handle the situation in which you have a buffer that may or may not grow to occupy a lot of memory.

Comment: If you have multiple pointers pointing to same address, then yes, you have update all the pointers when assigning new pointer returned by realloc() to the original pointer variable. That's not a too hard to do. But the fact you have to update too many pointers pointing to the same address sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Using the `BUFSIZ` macro in `stdio.h` and duplicating it whenever you run out of space is the common approach.

Comment: Also, some platform-dependent ugly hacks include using `malloc_size()` et al.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it sometimes happen that you don't know the size you need at that point so you either alloc a huge amount of memory (which doesn't sound too wise since you're probably not going to use it all) or you use realloc when the initial buffer size becomes too small. Are this two options valid?

In principle yes. In practice, with *modern OS* kernels and default system configurations it doesn't matter how much you allocate with *malloc*. You see, *malloc* allocates *address space*, not memory. You can allocate as much address space as you want it will not actually consume memory; of course the OS will employ several sanity checks on the value, for example on a system with only 2GiB memory available (RAM + swap) you can't allocate 3GiB. The usual configuration is that the largest chunk of address space allocatable in a single chunk is 50% of the available system memory.

Only when you actually write something to it, the OS will reserve memory for it. So don't use *calloc*, because it initializes memory with, i.e. write something into it.

So if you don't know how much exactly you'll need, just malloc a big chunk of address space, for which you know, by the characteristics of the kind of data processed, that it will easily hold whatever you're expecting. Once you've got it in memory, you can use *realloc* to shrink the allocation. For all implemantations that matter *realloc* will never move data when shrinking an allocation.

One thing to be aware of is memory overcommitment: Say you got 5 processes running on a system with 4GiB RAM, each allocation 1GiB, but not immediately writing to it. The OS will give them this address space, i.e. it overcommits memory (just like airlines overcommit flight seats). Some time later the processes start writing to it. At some point the system runs out of memory and the OS has to do something about it: It will start killing processes until there's again room to "breathe".

You can switch off memory overcommitment though; strongly recommended on high reliability systems.

Comment: Very interesting answer, however, if you write data sequential, so as soon as you write the first slice the entire buffer becomes allocated. So you don't gain too much. Only if you write your data at once. In any case, point taken regarding `calloc`/`malloc`, thanks.

Comment: @Meda, not the entire buffer.  If I malloc 1M of memory, and touch the first byte, the system will commit a page of memory (traditionally 4k but may be larger in modern systems) not the entire range.

Comment: Well, that makes it the best way to do it I guess (malloc'ing a huge value and don't worry about it, since any modern kernel will handle this nicely using the pagination technique you describe) I feel like I should change my accepted answer, and will do so until further evidence arises against it.

Answer (score 3):

You're right - those are pretty much your two choices.  You can work around the "multiple pointers" problem by abstracting a bit.  If instead of passing around the pointer returned by `malloc` directly, you stick it into another data structure:

```
struct malloc_wrapper
{
    void *p;
} wrapper;

wrapper.p = malloc(INITIAL_SIZE);
```

And pass pointers to that data structure around instead, you can change `p` at any time, and anybody who shares the pointer to your new structure will be updated accordingly:

```
void *tmp = realloc(somepointertowrapper->p, NEW_SIZE);

/* check tmp to ensure it's not NULL. That indicates a failure
 * to realloc and the original pointer passed into realloc 
 * remains valid.
 */

somepointertowrapper->p = tmp;
```

Comment: Always check the result from `realloc` before assigning it to a pointer to detect allocation failures. Keep in mind that `realloc` is a **HORRIBLE** interface because it tries to be all things to all people. I'm not kidding: you can avoid using `malloc` and `free` and do *everything* with `realloc`.